# Render Html file in offline mode(network not available) with library dependencies

Tags: html, iframe, html-parsing

There is an html file(a.html) which can have js libraries, css and there can be some functions in the included js libraries which loads some other html(b.html).
Now when the app is online, I set the iframe src as a.html(relative to server url) and it resolve all the dependencies(js, css libraries) automatically.

But when the app goes offline, I have all the dependencies(js, css and html)for this html in an offline db as records. Now I need to render this html in offline mode(network not available), how I can render the HTML file as there are dependencies(js, css and html) which needs to be resolved in order for the html to be rendered correctly.There is no offline/proxy server which can intercept the calls.

Do I need to manually parse the html to get all the script, link tags and replce their content online or is there any way where i can intercept the http calls from iframe and fetch the corresponding content from db and replace it inline?